# Calling function with TRUE returns wrong thing

Tags: php

I have this function

```
//$hasher is a phpass object.    
public function getHash( $check )
    {
    global $hasher;
    if ( $check == 'hash' )
        {
        return $hasher->HashPassword($this->password);
        }
    else if ( $check == 'check' )
        {
        return $hasher->CheckPassword($this->password, $this->getData('data')['password']);
        }
    else
        {
        return 'F*** off';
        }
    }
```

When i call it this is what i get

```
$obj->getHash('hash')
//getHash(): $2a$08$Uof.EzLkJI..........

$obj->getHash('check')
//getHash(): 1

$obj->getHash('dsadaldas') //and anything else in the brackets
//getHash():F*** off

$obj->getHash(TRUE)
//getHash(): $2a$08$3vNYnGVsf...
```

Why does calling the method with `TRUE` return the same as if i had called it with `'hash'` as an argument? Am i missing something here? I tried it with `switch()` and it still behaves the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a string such as `hash` evaluates to `true` when you use the equality operator (`==`):

You could use the identical (`===`) [operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead:

```
if ( $check === 'hash' )
```

This ensures that both the value of the variable and the type are the same.

Comment: Ah yes, the super same operators , i always forget about them :)) This does the trick. Thank you for the explanation, i hope it sticks with me longer.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you compare boolean (`true`) to string (`"hash"`), the string gets [converted to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), not the other way around.

Solution: use type-safe comparison (`===`)